# Fixed point of rational functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, rational-functions, fixed-points

Consider the following rational functions: $R_1(z)=z^2+z-1$ and $R_2(z)=z+\frac{1}{z}$.  The first has fixed points at $z^2+z-1=z \Rightarrow z=\pm 1.$  The second has a single fixed point at $\infty.$

> Show that neither of the two following propositions implies the other:
>
> > (i)  $R$ has all of it's fixed points at $\xi$
> >     (ii)  $R^{-1}\{\xi\}=\xi$

My reasoning that $(i)$ and $(ii)$ are not related is because of the following:

Notice that $R_1^{-1}(-1)=\{0,-1\}$  since $z^2+z-1=-1 \Rightarrow z^2+z=0 \Rightarrow z=0,-1$  But $R_1(0)=-1$. So $0$ is not a fixed point.

But considering $R_2$, we have $R_2(0)=R_2(\infty)=\infty$.  But $R^{-1}\{{\infty}\}=\{0, \infty\}$

Comment: So $R^{-1}(-1)=\{0,-1\}$, and $-1$ is not the only fixed point of $R$, as there is $1$ as well. So far it looks like the proposition is true (at least that is no counterexample). Also, are you working with rational functions or polynomials? Your title says one thing and your question another.

Comment: It's rational functions.  My textbook just offered two examples: $z+\frac{1}{z}$ and $z^2+2-1$ as examples as to why the proposition is false.  Also, $0$ is not a fixed point $R(0)=-1$.

Comment: I know that $0$ is not a fixed point, but that's irrelevant. What the proposition does is link two statements. In this case "$R$ has all its fixed points at $-1$" and "$R^{-1}(-1)=\{-1\}$". Those are both false, so the proposition is true (at least in this specific case).

Comment: I've modified the question.  I see where it came from now in my book.  I wrote down the comment as an iff, and the book has it phrased differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take for example the rational function

$R = \frac{z^2-2z+3}{z-1}$

$R = z \Leftrightarrow z^2-2z+3 = z(z-1) \Leftrightarrow 3z = 3 \Leftrightarrow z = 3$.
This is the only fixed point, so in this case (i) is satisfied.

However, $R^{-1}(3)$ contains more than just $3$: $\frac{z^2-2z+3}{z-1} = 3 \Leftrightarrow z^2-2z+3 = 3z-3 \Leftrightarrow z^2-5z+6 = 0$ which has two real roots (3 and 2).

So (i) is satisfied but (ii) is not, so (i) does not imply (ii).

The logic to give this example was that I was looking for a function $R = \frac{P}{Q}$ that had only one fixed point: so $P/Q = z$ has only one root $\Leftrightarrow P - Qz = 0$ is a degree $1$ complex polynomial.

That (ii) does not imply (ii) take $R_2 = \frac{z^2+2z-1}{z^2+3z-2}$. Consider $R_2 = 1 \Leftrightarrow z = 1$. Thus $R_2^{-1}(1) = \{1\}$. But consider $R_2(z) = z \Leftrightarrow z^3+2z^2-4z+1 = 0$ so there are 3 fixed points (1 and two other).

For the examples that emka gave, I think $R_1$ is actually used to show that (ii) does not imply (i) and $R_2$ is used to show that (i) does not imply (ii). While $R_2$ is a correct example, $R_1$ is not, but I believe they just interpreted the problem of proving (ii) implies (i) to mean that if a rational function has a fixed point then it has one and only one.

Comment: Ah, mercio is right... In the example, $R_1$ does contain $\infty$ as a fixed point and not the only fixed point of the function! You can just still consider my answer if you take out $\infty$ from the set of possible fixed points.

Answer (score 0):

For easy counterexamples, consider $R_1(z) = z$ and $R_2(z) = 0$, with $\xi = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You have already found that $R_2$ and $\xi = \infty$ is a situation where (i) is true and (ii) is false.

To complete the proof that they are independent (that neither implies the other) you need a situation where (i) is false and (ii) is true.

$R_1^{-1}(\{1\}) = \{1,-2\}$ and $R_1^{-1}(\{-1\}) = \{-1,0\}$ so in those cases, (ii) is false, so this doesn't work.
However, by looking at its *third* fixpoint, which is $\infty$, you have $R_1^{-1}(\{\infty\}) = \{\infty\}$, so there (ii) is true, and (i) is false because $R_1$ has two other fixpoints.